# Decentralized/P2P virtual private network (VPN)

Tags: windows, linux, open-source, vpn

I've been using OpenVPN to manage a network between a few computers, but it needs a central server and all data need to go through it. Additionally, changing the central server potentially means updating the whole network.

I'm looking for an open-source decentralized (P2P) VPN network that doesn't require a central server. Requirements:

- No central server (all peers are equal).
- Secure - all data must be encrypted. Peers that are allowed to connect should be managed by giving them a signed certificate that others can verify.
- Some peers don't have a public IP address (and this can change dynamically as some of them could be mobile); the software should be able to determine this and let peers forward traffic as needed.
- It should be possible to give peers fixed IP addresses in the internal network.
- The software needs to be actively maintained (to fix security issues).
- Low memory and CPU impact, if possible.
- I'm not looking for a [Social VPN](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Social_VPN), in particular, I don't want the system to rely on any social network.
- Linux and Windows support.
- The system should run as a system service, without requiring any GUI for administration.
- Optional IPv6 support would be beneficial (some peers can have a public IPv6 address, but not an IPv4 one).
- Optionally also internal DNS so all computers can be addressed by local names.

Answer (score 2):

### Tor

At first I thought [Tor](https://www.torproject.org/) was the solution for you, but it is an open network: anyone can join, so your "secure" requirement doesn't work.

### Tinc

So I would suggest taking a look at [tinc](http://www.tinc-vpn.org/). It's a p2p VPN where peers are authenticated through public keys and supports *some* NAT transversal, although it may not deal so well with hosts changing addresses because those are hardcoded in the config. It also has full IPv6 support. Short primer:

```
apt-get install tinc
mkdir -p /etc/tinc/net0/hosts
cat >> /etc/tinc/net0/tinc.conf <<EOF
Name = host
Mode = switch
Address = host.example.com
EOF
tinc -n net0 generate-keys
cat >> /etc/tinc/net0/tinc-up <<EOF
ifconfig $INTERFACE 172.16.242.43 netmask 255.255.255.255 up
EOF
chmod +x /etc/tinc/net0/tinc-up
tincd -d4 -D -n net0
```

Do this on each host, changing `tinc.conf` and `tinc-up` as appropriate. The `hosts` directory contains copies of each host's `tinc.conf` and sharing that configuration is out of band (e.g. I used git).

Also note that there were some serious security issues with Tinc, and it's not clear to me that the security design is sound.

### Wireguard

If I would start from scratch now, I would look at [Wireguard](https://www.wireguard.com/) which has better roaming support and sound crypto. Their [quickstart](https://www.wireguard.com/quickstart/) is excellent and basically amounts to:

```
apt install wireguard-dkms wireguard-tools
ip link add dev wg0 type wireguard
ip address add dev wg0 10.0.0.1/8
umask 077
wg genkey | tee /etc/wireguard/private.key | wg pubkey > /etc/wireguard/public.key
wg set wg0 listen-port 51820 private-key /etc/wireguard/private.key peer $(cat /etc/wireguard/peers/peer0.pub) allowed-ips 10.0.0.2/32 endpoint 192.0.2.1:51820
ip link set up dev wg0
```

This assumes the other has its public key already generated and stored in `/etc/wireguard/peers/peer0.pub`. That peer should be reachable at `192.0.2.1` and have a similar configuration with `10.0.0.2`  assigned on the `wg0` interface.

Have fun!